# Why does a proof by contradiction work?

Tags: logic

I know what a proof by contradiction is and how to use it, but I don't understand why a proof by contradiction proves the assertion. For example, to prove $A\implies B$, I suppose that $B$ is false and arrive at a contradiction. Why does that prove that $A\implies B$ is true ?

Comment: Intuitively, if you prove "$A$ and $\lnot B$" is impossible, this means $A$ and $\lnot B$ can't stay together, so if you know $A$, you'll know $B$.

Answer (score 4):

To prove $A\implies B$ by contradiction, you suppose $A$ AND not $B$ (i.e. $A\wedge \neg B$). Therefore, if you arrive to a contradiction, you proved that $A$ AND not $B$ is false, i.e. that not $A$ OR $B$ is true (i.e. that $\neg A\vee B$ is true), which is in fact $A\implies B$.

Comment: Oh, great ! thank you. And can you tel me why proof by induction work too ?

Comment: It's an other question, then you have to creat a new question.

Comment: ok, I asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462337/why-proof-by-induction-is-working

Comment: @Surb Does the proof by contradiction work when we have material conditionals like "If John is in the school then Sun is blue"? I mean a material conditional is just about truth values so if there is no "connection" between the hypothesis and the conclusion then it can't be applied?

Comment: Your statement is correct if John is an adult (as far as we suppose that adults don't go to school), but wrong if John is a Child (as far as schooling is mandatory for children). But there is no contradiction proof here since the sun is never blue.

Answer (score 1):

We may understand "$A$ contradicts $A'$" as "$A$ and $A'$ cannot hold simultaneously", which implies that $A$ implies the negation of $A'$; take $A' :=$ the negation of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume one wants to show $A \implies B$ and one is allowed to assume $A$ is true. In a proof by contradiction rather than deriving $B$ one tries to show that from $\lnot B$ one can derive $\lnot A$.

Note that $A$ and $\lnot A$ contradict each other.

One wants to reject contradictions because in classical logic from a contradiction anything follows. When anything follows then everything is true and one has what is called [trivialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivialism). To avoid trivialism, reject the assumption, $\lnot B$, when one can derive a contradiction from it.

Classical logic assumes that any statement has only one truth value, that is, $B$ is either true or false from the [principle of bivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_bivalence). So one can derive $B$ from $\lnot B$ being false. It is the only other truth value available. From there one can derive using conditional introduction or the [deduction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem) that $A \implies B$.

This is what happens as defined by inference rules in [classical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_logic) when one derives a contradiction. In [paraconsistent logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic) some contradictions are tolerated without leading to trivialism. But that would be a separate topic.