# Why proof by induction is working.

Tags: induction, axioms

I know how to make proofs by induction, but I don't understand why it prove that the propriety is true. It's in fact logical, but how to prove that proof by induction really prove the assertion.

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139579/why-is-mathematical-induction-a-valid-proof-technique?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Let prove the following theorem:

> **1)** $A(0)$ true,
>
> **2)** For all $n$ we have that $A(n)$ true $\implies A(n+1)$ true.
>
> Then $A(n)$ is true for all $n$.

Let denote $$\mathcal W=\{n\mid A(n)\ \text{ is false}\}.$$
Suppose by contradiction that $A$ is not true, i.e. that $|\mathcal W|\neq\emptyset$. Since $\mathcal W\subset \mathbb N$ and that $\mathbb N$ is well ordered, there is an $\alpha\in \mathcal W$ which is minimal. By **1)** we have that $\alpha\neq 0$. Therefore, by minimality of $\alpha$, we have that $A(\alpha-1)$ is true, which is a contradiction with **2)**. Therefore $A(n)$ is true for all $n$.

Comment: It's important, you are right. Thank you, I precise it.

Comment: Why $\alpha\neq 0$ is important ?

Comment: Because if $\alpha=0$, then $A(\alpha-1)$ is not defined.

Comment: I see. And if we would have only that $A(1)$ true and $A(0)$ false ? then we wouldn't need to use $\alpha\neq 1$ because $A(\alpha-1)$ would have sense. I understand.

Comment: Not at all. We need at least one $n$ for which $A(n)$ is true, otherwise $A$ is not necessarily true. If for example $A(n)$ is the property $e^{-n}<0$, you have that $A(n)$ true $\implies A(n+1)$ true, but the assertion is false since $e^x>0$ for all $x$. In your example, if $A(1)$ but $A(0)$ false, you can show the assertion only for $n\geq 1$, and in this case, you take $\mathcal W\subset \{2,3,...\}$. Is it more clear ?

Comment: @Surb More generally, for every false statement $P(n)$, you have $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ vacuously :p.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking. There are two things involved:

1. **Intuition.** You prove that your statement is true for $n=1$, and then from this you show it's true for $n=2$, from that for $n=3$ etc., just you do all these steps in one step.
2. **Axiom of induction.** One of its versions is
   $$ \forall P \Bigl( \Bigl(
     \forall n \bigl( \forall m (m<n \implies P(m)) \implies P(n) \bigr)
     \Bigr) \implies \Bigl(
     \forall n (P(n))
     \Bigr) \Bigr), $$
   where $P$ is a formula with one variable, and $n$, $m$ are natural numbers. This is a simpler version of the one mentioned in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Axiom_of_induction), because the first step -- proving that $P(0)$ is true, is an integral part of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

$\bf Definition:$ Inductive set.

An inductive set is a set S that satisfies:

1. $1\in S$.
2. $k\in S\implies k+1\in S$.

$\bf Definition: \Bbb N$

$\Bbb N$ is the set that satisfies:

1. $\Bbb N$ is inductive.
2. If $H$ is inductive, then $\Bbb N \subseteq H$.

Consider now, some proposition $P(n)$. Let $T=\{n\in \Bbb N: P(n)\}$ be the set of $n\in \Bbb N$ that make the proposition true..

Now, if we prove that $T$ is inductive, we will have proved that $T=\Bbb N$ (as we have from it's definition that $T\subseteq\Bbb N$): the proposition is true for all natural $n$.

Answer (score 0):

A proposition is true when $n=1$.

If it is true when $n=1$, then it is true when $n=2$.

If it is true when $n=2$, then it is true when $n=3$.

If it is true when $n=3$, then it is true when $n=4$.

If it is true when $n=4$, then it is true when $n=5$.

If it is true when $n=5$, then it is true when $n=6$.

and so on${}\,\ldots$

If this sequence can be shown to keep going, then it is true when $n$ is equal to any of $1,2,3,4,\ldots\,{}$.  That is induction.